# Should I only load javascript modules when needed, also if they are very tiny?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, frontend, amd

I'm working on a project using require.js and I am loading modules only if they are needed, like this

```
// only load accordion if needed
if ($('.accordion').length) {
    require(['Accordion'], function(Accordion) {
        Accordion.init();
    });
}
```

Now I'm wondering if this makes any sense, since the accordion.js module weighs less than 1kb... should I load all modules from startup and only init them when I need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are corner cases but as "standard" behavior we could say that if a js module is potentially used on your page, you should load it. Take into account that using cache, minification and modules grouping reduce a lot performance impact.

I wouldn't add extra logic to detect if the module is actually used or not. Extra logic is another potencial point of failure so probably it's not worth, specially for this case.

Comment: aggreed. You may have a look to Google closure compiler to minify all your js files and no longer care about this

Comment: or using require.js built in optimizer/minifier?

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on your performance needs. Most of the time, loading a 1KB file wouldn't have much of an impact on the client so you could aswell load it anyway.